# How to pass argument to ARGV from a text file in Perl

Tags: perl, argv

I have a list of arguments to pass into a Perl script, using `ARGV`. The 4th argument, is a server's name, but I want to pass it a text file with a list of servers called `servers.txt`. How do I pass that in and use it as an argument to `ARGV`?

Sample file `servers.txt`:

```
server1
server2
server3
```

Working code:

```
# usage example: ./test.pl Jul 05 2010 <server> <logfile>
# $ARGV[0]=Jul
# $ARGV[1]=05
# $ARGV[2]=2010
# $ARGV[3]=server
# $ARGV[4]=/pathoffile

use strict;
use warnings;

my($mon,$day,$year,$server,$file) = @ARGV;
open(my $fh,"ssh $server cat $file |") or die "can't open log $server:$file: $!\n";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /.* $mon $day \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} $year:.*(ERROR:|backup-date=|backup-size=|backup-time=|backup-status)/) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already know how to open a file for reading, so what exactly is the part that you are missing?  Are you intending to cat a file on the remote server, or write a file through the ssh pipe, or...?

Comment: @ether: yes, its doing a cat on a log file remotely reading it in for the regex. do I open the servers.txt file and place that in a while loop too?
Is it efficient to have a while loop inside another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for `xargs`.

Using this stand-in for your `test.pl` that shows the command executed

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

$" = "][";
print "[@ARGV]\n";
```

running

```
$ xargs -I{} ./test.pl Jul 05 2010 {} logfile <servers.txt
```

produces

```
[Jul][05][2010][server1][logfile]
[Jul][05][2010][server2][logfile]
[Jul][05][2010][server3][logfile]
```